# Does anyone know where font size for product descriptions is defined?

Tags: code

I'm trying to make all fonts larger on a few Magento Go sites - in the code I've found all of the other locations to increase font sizes for headers and so forth but can't seem to find the location of product description font. If anyone knows where it is this info would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the `style.css` file in your template folder.

File Location : `/skin/frontend/base/YOUR TEMPLATE/css/style.css`

to find the exact element you can use firebug extension over firefox

`https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/`

Comment: Don't bother with Firebug, no need for extra extensions unless you're a medium-core developer, Firefox and Chrome have built in developer functions that will easily let you select html elements and find their css class so you can locate it in style.css. Chrome F12 developer even lets you real-time edit the loaded page css to see if you're getting the desired effect.